# How to eliminate straight lines

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the output of canny edge detector below

[image]

I want to eliminate those straight lines. The output image should only contain the oval shapes. I tried using findContours() and finding the largest contour and eliminating it. But i'm not happy with the result. 
Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Comment: You could take a look at [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to detect straight edges: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: Thanks but I dont really want to use hough lines because I think its slow. I'll try it before jumping to conclusions. But is there a faster method?

Comment: You can try applying vertical and horizontal derivatives in two steps to filter some straight lines. Also you can try to check if a contour is closed. Try to provide some input images and a piece of code.

Comment: I think you should focus on finding the oval shapes rather than straight lines. If you do the straight lines then you will need to find a way of removing the other non straight lines... but if you look for the oval shapes you will get what you want at the end... Maybe canny is not the best for finding the oval, maybe just thresholding is better... it is hard to say without the original image

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to detect the oval shapes *and* don't want to use [HoughLines](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html), you could use the [SimpleBlobDetector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html) as follows:

*Note: I coded this in python since it is faster to implement. The code is pretty straightforward to convert to C++ IMO*

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("remove_lines.jpg")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply morph closing to improve the connection between ovals (complete the ovals)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
imgray = cv2.morphologyEx(imgray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel=kernel)

# Set parameters for blob detection
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
# This is to remove any "small" blobs
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 200
# bit easy on the circularity here, circle = 1
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.7
# Convexity = Area of Blob / Area of its convex hull 
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.1
# Measure how elongated the shape is, line = 0, circle = 1, very easy here as well
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(imgray)

im_with_points = cv2.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), 
cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_points)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the exact oval shape?